# Selecting AR($p$) order using cross-validation

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, autoregressive

I am playing around with some simulations to see if it is possible to select the order of an AR($p$) process using cross-validation. I simulate a number of observations of AR($2$) using `arima.sim()`, I split the sample into the training set that contains 75% of the simulated observations and the test set that contains the remaining observations. I estimate the test MSE for $p=1,\ldots,50$ and produce the following plot.
[image]
Of course there is a certain amount of randomness from simulation to simulation but I would say that it works very poorly if at all judging from the simulations. I would expect to the see the smallest value around $2$ but it is rarely the case. I would expect that as $p$ increases the model would start to overfit and that would lead to an increase in the estimated test MSE. Sometimes the picture looks like that but it is not a prevalent pattern.

> Does increasing $p$ actually lead to overfitting? Can cross-validation be used for time series in general and to select the order of an AR($p$) process in particular? If no, what is the reason cross-validation does not work for time series or at least in this example?

Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. This is the `R` code that I use to produce the plot and play around with the simulations.

```r
n <- 1e3
prop <- .75
set.seed(7)
x <- arima.sim(list(ar = c(.2, .75)), n = n)
train <- 1:floor(prop * n)
x_train <- x[train]
x_test <- x[-train]
mse <- c()
for (p in 1:50)
    {
        arfit <- ar.yw(x_train, aic = FALSE, order.max = p)
        mse[p] <- mean((predict(arfit, n.ahead = length(x_test))$pred - x_test)^2)
    }

png(file = "mse.png", width = 1200, height = 600, res = 150)
plot(mse, pch = 20, xlab = "Order", main = "Estimated test MSE (the actual order is 2)", ylab = "MSE")
dev.off()
```

Comment: 90% of data in the training set seems to be quite a lot, what do you obtain by increasing the amount of data in the test set? And I guess you are training on the 90% first data, and test testing on the 10% last data points?

Comment: @CamilleGontier Thanks for your comment. I essentially get the same impression if I split 75% training and 25% test (I updated the picture and the code). The plots are all over the place even though I would expect the minimum somewhere close the actual order (which is $2$). Yes, I am training on the 75% first data and then training on the last 25%.

Comment: I realize your analysis is based on a single data set x. You can notice that results are going to greatly vary if you use an other random seed. I would recommend to perform the same analysis, but to average results over different realisations of x

Comment: I would do time series cross validation via rolling windows rather than a single training-test split. Also, it seems you have formatted your questions as a quotation. If it is not a quotation, I would not use such formatting, as it invites the reader to think you are quoting something.